# Finalizer in R modifying objects - thread safe?

Tags: r, thread-safety, finalizer

In an R package, I manage some external objects. I want to release them after the corresponding R object (an environment) has been garbage collected. There is a reason why I cannot release the external resources right away. Therefore I need to somehow save the information that the object has been garbage collected and use this information at a later time. The approch is implemented basically like the following:

Environment objects are created with some ID. I have some environment `managingEnv`, where I collect the information about the finalized objects in a vector of IDs of objects. When the objects are finalized, the finalizer writes their IDs into the `managingEnv`.

```
managingEnv <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
managingEnv$garbageCollectedIds <- c()

createExternalObject <- function(id) {
  ret <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
  ret$id <- id
  reg.finalizer(ret, function(e) {
     managingEnv$garbageCollectedIds <- c(managingEnv$garbageCollectedIds, e$id)
  })
  ret
}
```

If I then create some objects and run the garbage collection, the approach seems to work and I have at the end all IDs collected in the `managingEnv` and could later perform my action to release all these objects.

```
> createExternalObject(1)
<environment: 0x000002307ff36920>
> createExternalObject(2)
<environment: 0x000002307e94d390>
> createExternalObject(3)
<environment: 0x000002307e94ac90>
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells  568005 30.4    1299461 69.4  1299461 69.4
Vcells 1519057 11.6    8388608 64.0  2044145 15.6
> managingEnv$garbageCollectedIds
[1] 2 1 3
```

Although the approach seems to work, I have encountered some instability in my package and R crashes sometimes randomly. After some research into the problem, I came to the conclusion that the approach that I use might be not safe.

The documentation of `reg.finalizer` says:

> Note:
> R's interpreter is not re-entrant and the finalizer could be run
> in the middle of a computation.  So there are many functions which
> it is potentially unsafe to call from ‘f’: one example which
> caused trouble is ‘options’.  Finalizers are scheduled at garbage
> collection but only run at a relatively safe time thereafter.

Is my approach really safe? Can I change this code to make if safe(r) or find another solution to the problem described above?

**EDIT**: I found the reasons for the instability in other parts of the code. So it seems like the approach described above is safe. I would still be interested in more details about how to know which operations are "potentially unsafe" in finalizers, to be able to reason that the approach described here is safe.

Comment: Your approach *as shown here* is safe: there’s no possibility of “instability” or crashes. And, in particular, R doesn’t support concurrent multithreading in pure R code anyway, due to the GIL. But I’m assuming that your actual logic which handles the `garbageCollectedIds` is in native code. You haven’t provided enough information to diagnose any potential issues there.

Comment: No it is not in native code. It works pretty much exactly like the code shown. I don't use native code at all in my package. That's why I was very surprised to get crashes of R and came to suspect that this approach could be the problem.

Comment: Alright, I’m stumped. What are these external objects? How are you releasing them? When do the crashes happen? During the regular running of R or at shutdown?

Comment: The external objects are Julia objects, which are managed separately by Julia. Only the ID of these objects is passed to R. I only communicate via TCP, so there is no memory sharing or any low-level native stuff that could lead to crashes. I also don't use any other R libraries, only basic R. Releasing is simply sending a message via TCP to Julia to release the objects. The crashes happen at random times during the execution. I suspect it has also to do with saving and restoring the workspace. In a clean workspace, the crashes do not appear.